# How is the "getchar()" function able to take multiple characters as input?

Tags: c

Here is a basic character counting program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    long nc = 0;

    while(getchar() != EOF)
        nc++;
    printf("%ld\n" , nc);
}
```

When I am entering "abcde" as an input, it displays a value of 6(after triggering the EOF test), +1 for the newline character. But my doubt is that `getchar()`, as its name itself suggests, takes only 1 character into account. But when I am entering "abcde" at one go itself, it still works. Why is this so? What problem am I doing here?

Comment: Each pass through the loop reads only one char. nd counts the number of such passes. I fail to see why you would consider it mysterious.

Comment: Remove the loop and see again!

Answer (score 26):

Standard input, by default, is line-buffered with an interactive device. This means that your program won't see any input at all until a complete line is ready, in your case when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. One good reason for this is that if the user types her 8 character password, then hits backspace 8 times, and then types her username and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then your program only gets her username, and never sees the correction, which is usually what you want when your shell gives the opportunity to edit your input before you send it anywhere.

So what happens is essentially this:

1. You call `getchar()`. No input is available, so it waits.
2. You press <kbd>a</kbd>. It's not the end of a line, so no input is sent to your program, `getchar()` has nothing to read, so it still waits.
3. You press <kbd>b</kbd>. It's not the end of a line, so no input is sent to your program, `getchar()` has nothing to read, so it still waits.
4. You press <kbd>c</kbd>. It's not the end of a line, so no input is sent to your program, `getchar()` has nothing to read, so it still waits.
5. You press <kbd>d</kbd>. It's not the end of a line, so no input is sent to your program, `getchar()` has nothing to read, so it still waits.
6. You press <kbd>e</kbd>. It's not the end of a line, so no input is sent to your program, `getchar()` has nothing to read, so it still waits.
7. You press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now it *is* the end of a line, so the input `"abcde\n"` is sent to your program.
8. `getchar()` now has input to read, so it returns `'a'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
9. Immediately, `getchar()` has more input to read from the rest of the characters in that line, so it returns `'b'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
10. Immediately, `getchar()` has more input to read from the rest of the characters in that line, so it returns `'c'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
11. Immediately, `getchar()` has more input to read from the rest of the characters in that line, so it returns `'d'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
12. Immediately, `getchar()` has more input to read from the rest of the characters in that line, so it returns `'e'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
13. Immediately, `getchar()` has more input to read from the rest of the characters in that line, so it returns `'\n'`, increments `nc`, and loops back to wait for input.
14. If you signified end-of-input, perhaps by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, then `getchar()` has nothing to read and knows there will never be anything to read, so it returns `EOF` and your loop ends. If it were *not* end-of-input, then `getchar()` would just again wait here for you to enter a new line of input.

So what actually happened here is that `getchar()` did nothing until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, probably before you even took your finger off the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it ran six times and consumed the six characters of input that you typed. But despite `getchar()` running six times, *you* were only prompted to enter something once (twice, if you include having to type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>), because `getchar()` will only wait for your input when it doesn't already have input available and waiting.

Back in the days where standalone terminals were common, the actual terminal device might not even transmit any characters to the computer until the end of a line, and could have a small amount of on-board memory to allow for this kind of local line-based editing, so the computer itself might literally never see it until end-of-line. On the kind of modern PC many people use, the operating system, down at the terminal driver level, will more probably be buffering these characters itself, and just presenting them and making them available to your program one line at a time (unless you specifically tell it that you want characters immediately, of course).

Answer (score 4):

When you type in `abcde\n` (`\n` generated from <kbd>Enter</kbd>), it gets flushed into the standard input stream (`stdin`).

> `getchar()`, as its name itself suggests, takes only 1 character into account

Yes, that's right. But notice that `getchar` is used in a *loop* which loops until `getchar` returns `EOF`. Also, recall that `getchar` reads input from the `stdin`.

So, in the first iteration, after you type in the data, `getchar` reads the first character `a`. In the second iteration, it doesn't wait for input since the `stdin` still contains `bcde\n` and hence, reads the next character `b` and so on.

Finally, the loop breaks when you trigger `EOF`. Then, the `printf` gets executed (printing `6` since six characters were read) and the program ends.

Comment: Okay, but each time you call `getchar`, you have to input something. Why does that happen then, if `bcde\n` is still there in `stdin`

Comment: `getchar` waits for input _if_ the `stdin` is empty. Otherwise, it doesn't and consumes the next character.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @crowman that's what happens. I would suggest you try `ctrl+D` instead of `enter` (i.e., `\n`) to end the std input stream (as std input is line buffered). As you'd have to press `ctrl+D` again to end the loop. You could use a debugger to see the process. I'm attaching an image ([result of gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nc5v.png)) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` reads next characters from standard input's buffer, and returns it, since you feed six characters - "abcde\n" - into the standard input, and you are calling `getchar` in a while loop, that means the loop body was run for six times, it read the chars one by one. You can test this by:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("got %c\n", c);
    nc++;
}
```